# Ім'я Лерія в українській мові

Tags: переклад

Нещодавно почула, як одна жіночка звернулась до своєї доньки на ім'я Лерия (рос). Спочатку подумала, що це похідне від Лера, Валерия.

Почала шукати в мережі. Виявилось, що в російській мові існує ім'я Лерия. Чи є відповідник українською?

Comment: А де Ви знайшли, що в російській мові існує такє ім'я?

Comment: Відповідник у якому сенсі: ім'я, яке звучить схоже, чи ім'я, яке означає те саме (перекладається з мови-оригіналу так само), чи як?

Comment: ставлю мінус, додайте джерела, будь ласка, поки що незрозуміло, де ви шукали і де знайшли інформацію.

Answer (score 4):

Заглянемо в [Словник власних імен](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/ua/elib.exe?Z21ID=&I21DBN=UKRLIB&P21DBN=UKRLIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=online_book&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=FF=&S21STR=ukr0001272) та подивимося на ім'я Валерія (я також наткнувся на це [джерело](https://zogo.info/znachennya-imeni-valeriya-ukraynskoyu-movoyu/), де пише, що ім'я Лерія походить від Валерія), але як бачимо, такого скорочення як Лерія там немає.

Однак, мені вдалося знайти українців із такими іменами - Лерія Кот (хоч варто зазначити, що її справжнє ім'я Олена) та Лерій Леонідович Макаренко (ось його [книга](http://www.nibu.kiev.ua/files/el_res/biobiblpokazhch/Vyp6_Makarenko_Pokaczhchyk.pdf)).

Тобто таке ім'я як Лерія справді існує і, напевно, воно таки походить від імені Валерія (і утворилося так само як скорочення Лера, просто було упущенно частину "ва-" і більше не було зроблено ніяких змін).

Answer (score 3):

У словниках імен чи власних назв імені Лерія, на жаль, не знайшла. Однак на сайті  [zogo.info](https://zogo.info/znachennya-imeni-valeriya-ukraynskoyu-movoyu/) знайшла як скорочення від "Валерія":

> Коротка форма імені **Валерія**. Валера, Лера, Леруня, Леруся, Леруха, Леруша, Лека, Валя, Валюня, Валюся, Валюха, Валюша, Валечка, Вака, Вава, ***Лерія***, Вале.

Трішки й моїх думок:

Також ще може бути й інший варіант, який "на слух" звучить майже однаково: [Лейрія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F).

> **Лейрі́я** — муніципалітет і місто в Португалії, в окрузі Лейрія.

Цілком можлива й така аналогія, адже є, наприклад, *ім"я Володимир і місто Володимир (Росія), Володимир-Волинський (Україна); ім"я Ярослав, і місто Ярослав (Польща)* та ін.

Правда, інформація дещо сумнівна.